# Error when comparing values in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, select, count

I write simple procedure.

```
DECLARE
  connection_id LINE.CONNECTION_ID%TYPE := 11009;
  tmp_integer INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO tmp_integer FROM LINE WHERE LINE.CONNECTION_ID = 11009;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(connection_id);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(tmp_integer);
END;
```

Result of the launch:

```
11009
3
```

It is good result. I have only 3 rows where CONNECTION_ID is 11009.
After modification:

```
DECLARE
  connection_id LINE.CONNECTION_ID%TYPE := 11009;
  tmp_integer INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO tmp_integer FROM LINE WHERE LINE.CONNECTION_ID = connection_id;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(connection_id);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(tmp_integer);
END;
```

But in this case I gain strange result:

```
11009
30997
```

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the name of your PL/SQL variable to be different from the column name in the table, e.g. v_connection_id.

Comment: Yes, this is a mistake. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome - An additional note - it is a good general practice to adopt a coding style that reduces the chances of a collision between PL/SQL variables and column names, e.g. v_COLUMN_NAME or vCOLUMN_NAME - in your code this was easy to spot, but packages with long cursor definitions and many variables can lead to lots of lost time debugging.